# how to return an empty array with array.map

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to return an empty array if obj.chk != true
to check if no checked toDos

```
function listChk() 
{
    if (!chkExist('./toDoArr')) {console.log('Please create toDo list first!')}
    else {

        let toDoArr = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./toDoArr'))

        let chkToDoArr = toDoArr.map(function (obj) {
            if (obj.chk === true){
               console.log( obj.toDo)
               return obj.toDo
            }
        });
        console.log(chkToDoArr) // >>  [ undefined, undefined ]

        if (chkToDoArr.length < 1) 
        console.log('no checked toDos or empty list');
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: The only way to return an empty array from `.map()` is if your input is an empty array. You have to re-think how you approach this, since you cannot embed the logic in the mapping function.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you need to use is [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of map. For example:

```
let chkToDoArr = toDoArr.filter(function (obj) {
  return obj.chk === true
})

console.log(chkToDoArr) // >>  []
```

Filter returns an array of results where the comparing function returns a truthy.

Comment: thank you, but the return is an array of obj but btw it's working like this  ```console.log (chkToDoArr) // >> [ { chk: true, id: 1, toDo: 'todo' }, { chk: true, id: 2, toDo: 'todo1' } ]``` --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ```if (chkToDoArr.length < 1) console.log('no checked toDos or empty list'); else { for (let val of chkToDoArr){ console.log( val.toDo ) /*>> todo todo1*/ } }```

Comment: I think you need to be more explicit with what you are trying to achieve, as I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let chkToDoArr = toDoArr.filter(obj => obj.chk).map(obj => obj.toDo)
```

1. filter method checks if received elemet prop is true returns that elemen. on the false returns
   nothing. if on the array all objects element prop(chk) is false
   returns empty array
2. second action is map filtered data and return
       array with toDo prop

Comment: you don't understand what going on here? question was if not exist any (or it is false) obj.chk prop return empty array otherwise return todo prop... that is solution